# Hide content in front page using conditional wordpress

Tags: wordpress, if-statement

Currently I am trying to hide a script in my header in some single posts using id and it is working, but I want the script not to be shown in front page, home and pages, I have not been able to get it because the script is still shown in front page, home and pages.

I am doing something wrong?

This is my code, but my script is still displayed on front, home, pages:

```
<?php if( !is_home() && !is_front_page() && !is_page()  ) : ?>
    <!-- No Script -->
        <?php elseif  (is_single( array( 1, '32438', '10506'  ) ) ) : ?>
        <?php else : ?>
    <script></script>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Isn't the condition you are using self explanatory? basically you are saying that if "is not home AND is not front page AND is not page then no script". The three conditions have to be met to not show the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() || is_page()  ) : ?>
<!-- No Script -->
    <?php elseif  (is_single( array( 1, '32438', '10506'  ) ) ) : ?>
    <?php else : ?>
<script></script>
    <?php endif; ?>
```